# Workflow that will copy multiple documents from one library to several others

Tags: designer-workflow

I'm using SP 2010 Designer Enabled.  I have a need to create a workflow that will copy multiple documents in one list to several other lists on another site.  Let me explain like this:

Let's say Documents 1, 2, and 3 (all PDFs) are in Document List A on Server A.  I need to copy all three PDFs to Document List X, Y, and Z on Server B. (I need to copy them because I'll need unique copies in each library for different people).  I'd rather not use a script that I have to hard code each time but I'm open to anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you want to move within the same farm but different site collection or totally different farm?

Comment: Good question. They are in the same farm but in different sites

Comment: Same farm. I have a site that contains several subsites. I use these subsites as "templates" for classes to deliver learning content. I am hoping to create a master library on the parent site that I can then copy content to a newly copied subsite. At this point I'm so frustrated. I'm being asked to do things in SP that I feel can be done but I'm not a SharePoint trained person. At this point, I'll even take a workflow that will copy with the subsite. Right now, I have a workflow that will copy everything but when I copy that subsite to a new location, the WF breaks.

Comment: So I just tried a reusable WF and it only kind of works. I can associate it with the new list but it won't copy until I edit the WF and reassociate the destination lists. After all that, I might as well just make a new one every time. What I think I need is some kind of custom solution to copy a block of documents from a library in one site to multiple libraries in another site.